# javascript object inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working on react and using ant design list component, made it stateless child component to use it everywhere.  my datasource (props.datasource in this case) is array of objects. List component iterate through each object.

On title and description of list component i want to pass props which i am not able to do. For now it is title = {item.line1} and description = {item.city}, here "line1" and "city" are predefined but i want to use props. From parent component i want to pass title="line1" and then use it as {props.title} in list component title field.

```
<List
dataSource={props.dataSource}
renderItem={(item) => (
<List.Item
  key={item.id}
>
  <List.Item.Meta
    avatar={
      <Avatar
        icon={<CheckOutlined />} //anything 
      />
    }
    title={item.line1}
    description={item.city}
  />
</List.Item>
)}
/>
```

with all my efforts i am not able to do this, How Can i add objects inside an object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, what you need is destructure props to child component, it could achieved like this:

```js
<List
  dataSource={props.dataSource}
  renderItem={(item) => (
    <List.Item
      key={item.id}
    >
      <List.Item.Meta
        avatar={
          <Avatar
            icon={<CheckOutlined />} //anything 
          />
        }
        {...item} // Like this
      />
    </List.Item>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: item consist of data such as line1, line2, city, state, and more in this particular case. So if i want to know city for example how should i write ? Manually writing {item.city} works fine but how to combine props with item?

Comment: in child component you will receive all of those you mentioned. `props.city`, `props.line1`, `props.xxxxx`

Comment: yes i will recieve all props, i need to write item.xxxxx to get value of xxxxx printed. xxxxxx is a props and i am not able to write this props with item.

Comment: I mean, all the properties inside `item` are spread into the child component into `props`. This way you will access in child component to `props.whateverITEMhasonIt` and so on.

Comment: Dear, i am not able to access city. can you please let me know what should be title = ? And also explain me for further use.

Comment: of course, could you start some codebox with desired code to explain on it?

Comment: check : https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-ix9ir

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere to access property of objects by : expression[expression]

and by writing title={item[`${props.title}`]} the problem was solved.

Thanks